# curlftpfs can touch but not update modify time

Tags: curlftpfs

I've got a ftp mounted using curlftpfs.

When I touch a file that doesn't exist, it creates the file. When I touch a file that already exists, it doesn't update the mtime.

I've tried chmod 777 the file on the server. I still can't change the mtime. But I can however edit the file perfectly fine.

I do notice that when you mount curlftpfs, the files are mounted as root:root. Does it make a difference?